# Use relative path to include libraries for MASM in Visual Studio

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2017, masm

I tried to add my path `C:\masm32` to `Include Paths` in `Project -> Properties -> Microsoft Macro Assembler -> General -> Include Paths`. The assembler then compiles my project with the command:

`ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\test.obj" /l "C:\masm32" /W3 /errorReport:prompt /Tatest.asm"`

Which did include my path to libraries but in my code it keeps telling me to have error at only the part for the `\include\kernel32.inc`

My includes:

`...
includelib \lib\kernel32.lib   ;These two .lib files seem to have
includelib \lib\masm32.lib     ;no error even if i remove the .inc files
include \include\kernel32.inc  ;It only reports error for .inc files
include \include\masm32rt.inc  ;cannot open file: \include\kernel32.inc
...`

Does this have anything to do with the same keyword used for `include \include\...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the leading `\` so it became `include include\kernel32.inc`.